# How to keep a java list in memory synced with a table in database?

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, architecture

I want to perform a search of a inputs in a list. That list resides in a database. I see two options for doing that-

1. Hit the db for each search and return the result.
2. keep a copy in memory synced with table and search in memory and return the result.

I like the second option as it will be faster.  However I am confused on how to keep the list in sync with table.

example : I have a list L = [12,11,14,42,56]
and I receive an input : 14

I need to return the result if the input does exists in the list or not. The list can be updated by other applications.  I need to keep the list in sync with table.

What would be the most optimized approach here and how to keep the  list in sync with database?

Is there any way my application can be informed of the changes in the table so that I can reload the list on demand.

Comment: Assuming you *need* to use a database, just stick with #1.  Databases are exactly designed and optimized for this purpose.

Comment: And if #1 becomes too performance hungry, a write-through cache will reduce the hits to the DB.

Comment: How about if #1 is still too slow. Is there anyway to keep the in memory list synced?

Comment: @kayaman In case the application doesn't control writes? what if we can only read.

Comment: @SteveSmith "Assuming you need to use a database" <- do we have a better choice? that list needs to be persistent regardless of this application's life cycle.

Comment: You could look into Hazelcast.  I don't know if it would be any faster than a database though.

Comment: You are sure to have problems with synchronization and dirty reads unless you handle isolation and transactions with the database correctly.  Let clients pull the data when it's needed from the database.  You should stop worrying about optimizing until you get the behavior working correctly.  Once you have it, profile your code to see where it might improve.  You may be surprised to learn that you have bigger issues than this list.

Comment: with the example you have given i don't see why #1 would be slow. Doing a simple query like that should be very fast unless you have set up your table structure in a really strange way (like having persisted the whole list as a single string field or something equaly horrible).

Comment: "How about if #1 is still too slow." - Have you done any benchmarking to see if it would be too slow?  I'd be amazed if it was.

Comment: Can Elements be removed from DB? Or just added?

Comment: Static Memory is the only way to keep alive in the memory for all time in the application.

Comment: if the list is not updated frequently but we can't afford the latency of a scheduled refresh. In that case, we are only left with an in-memory list synced with a database, So how to achieve this with minimalistic delay? 
Can writing a trigger over the table, which could hit a REST request after each update, be a potential solution?
And @Fildor yes elements can be added and removed from third party applications.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of recreating your own implementation of something that already exists, I would leverage Hibernate's Second Level Cache (2LC) with an implementation such as EhCache.

By using a 2LC, you can specify the time-to-live expiration time for your entities and once they expire, any query would reload them from the database.  If the entity cache has not yet expired, Hibernate will hydrate them from the 2LC application cache rather than the database.

If you are using Spring, you might also want to take a look at `@Cachable`.  This operates at the component / bean tier allowing Spring to cache a result-set into a named region.  See their documentation for more details.

Comment: That would be a scheduled refresh. Isn't there any solution for an on-demand refresh? Where you can reload only if the data changes. Like writing a trigger in mysql which could hit a REST call to the application?

Comment: Yes, most cache providers give the developer a way to manually evict entries.  You could use that in an on-demand job where you evict the data and then rerun the Hibernate queries to repopulate the cache as needed.

Comment: The trigger idea is quite interesting, if your scenario is that the data isn't updated frequently and reading the data is expensive. An update trigger could update some simple table that's quick to read with a timestamp of the update. You can frequently check that simple table. If the timestamp > your last refresh timestamp, you should refresh your in-memory data.

Comment: But instead of using a MySQL database trigger, you write a scheduled job in the application that houses the cache so that the poll fires when the application is guaranteed to be available and not just fire from the database side without any knowledge of whether the application is up and available.

Answer (score 0):

To satisfied your requirement, you should control the read and write in one place, otherwise, there will always be some unsync case for the data.